# What is the XP stat on a ship for?

Tags: vega-conflict

In Fleet Manager, when I select a ship, along with the DPS, Health, etc. there is an XP stat, but I have no idea what it actually means, or affects. You can see it in this screenshot[image: Rancor ship XP stat]

So, my question is how is the XP stat calculated, and what is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What the XP Value Means

It 100% is used to determine the ship's LEVEL!  As a matter of fact it's directly related to (as in it's another way to represent) the ship's LEVEL. When you add up all the ships in a fleet (VEGA calculation) you get a fleet level and that determines what targets you can and cannot attack (and can attack your fleet).  The XP value in the Fleet Manager determines you FLEET's experience level.  Your fleet can only battle other fleets within 5 levels of it's own.  During gameplay the level of your fleet is displayed to the right in the fleets HUD.  So for an example, a fleet with level 20 can only attack fleet levels 15-25.  This is also true for fleets attacking you, your fleet could only be attacked by 15-25 level fleets.

### Don't Load Up On Tech

So make sure you don't just load up on tons of tech!  Be choosy and only spend that experience (XP) where needed.  For example, if you want to throw together just a cargo fleet (a fleet used to carry as much cargo as possible from a battle) then one might want to ONLY equip a `Basic Cargo III` and maybe a `Rail Driver I`.  That way your experience stays as low as possible and you can shoot enemies in your level range at a distance.

### How Can You Calculate These Values?

I use a great little site called `Vega Conflict Ship Calc`.  The address of the website is http://www.vegashipcalc.co.uk/ and it will save you tons of time and resources to try your builds out here first THEN apply them in VEGA!

### Great Starter Build

I have already put a great build up that is used to AUTO defeat VEGA fleets from levels 20-23.  I also made it a tinyURL because the actual URL is `H U G E`.  Try building this fleet in VEGA and go seek out a VEGA fleet (not a normal fleet) that is a level 20-23.  Attack the fleet and let AI do all the work!  This build can guarantee an `instant repair`.  Instant Repairs are where you can recall your fleet and remove all the ships.  By placing them in the fleet ONE AT A TIME and doing a repair you can INSTANTLY repair the entire fleet!
[Instant Repair Fleet For VEGA Fleets 20-23](http://tinyurl.com/vega20to25)

Comment: Just to address the users that want to edit/revise my post...  There is a reason that there are caps everywhere!  It's intended to make that word intense and stand out so the sentence is not mistaken for a different meaning...  Example: `The XP value in the Fleet Manager determines you FLEET's experience level.` Someone might think I'm talking about ships and I'm explicitly talking about FLEETs!  Example: `Try building this fleet in VEGA and go seek out a VEGA fleet (not a normal fleet) that is a level 20-23.` It's important not to confuse normal fleets!

Comment: Great answer. I can only hope that free instant repair fleets survive the coming great grand rebalance...

Answer (score 1):

It is basically a measurement of the technology level present in your ships.

The XP value of ships in a fleet are added together to determine the fleet level.

Comment: You should post an answer! The vega ship calc is a very handy tool like you said.

Comment: Posted the response as an answer and removed it as a comment (so not to clutter).  This game is way too addictive! - Thanks

Answer (score -2):

In most games that have XP gauges, it comes from defeating enemies, completing certain tasks, finding special items etc. It's highly likely that it's the case for this game as well.

Comment: It's definitely not. The XP on a ship never changes. It is not a gauge. It has something to do with the equipment that the ship has, but I'm not sure how it is calculated, and what it affects, if anything.